# How to change tiling layout in KDE 4.7

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde, window-manager

I am using KDE 4.7.4 and enabled tiling. Is there a way to see the current tiling layout and to change the tiling layout for a specific desktop, similar to what you would do in the Awesome window manager? I see that you can change the default tiling layout in system settings, but I do not see an applet or anything similar for viewing the current tile layout and I do not even see a place in the keyboard shortcut configuration where I could set a key sequence to change it.

Answer (score 0):

SystemSettings > Keyboard > GlobalShortcuts > Kwin